Expected return on treasury basis trades
There have been a lot of articles on Treasury basis trades. What types of levels are targeted in this trade? Am I correct in seeing that the basis seems to be less than 10 cents in the dollar so almost not worthwhile when you factor in costs.
Is it that more trades are done in the off the run bond basket deliverables?
Thanks
